# How to pass device width to other screen inside initState in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to pass deviceWidth and deviceHeight to other screen. Here is my code:

```
class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    var deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/home");
    });
  }
```

But when I run this code, I am getting this error:

```
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MediaQuery>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _SplashPageState.initState() completed.
```

How to fix this? And the way I'm doing is right way?

Comment: Hello, why don't you call  deviceHeight and deviceWidth on other screen? passing data from previous page is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that accessing anything from the context from init state might not guarantee that the widget is already built. The solution is to trigger a method after the first initial render of the frame. That way, the context is properly updated with the current context of that the widget has.

Try this example code i wrote:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      var deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      var deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      print(deviceHeight);
      print(deviceWidth);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

This would print the width and height of the screen. Without any errors. This is because i am using

```
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
});
```

Essentially what it does is the method will be executed after the first frame is built. more info here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html

I would like to add that it's a weird use case to get the screen width and height from within init state. There might be a better approach to what you are trying to achieve.